# Add validation constraints on mapped = false fields for a specific validation group

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I'd like to be able to add in a Form class additional validation constraints for a specific validation group. How could I do that ?

Since Symfony 2.1, adding a validation while building the form looks like this :

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MinLength;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

$builder
    ->add('firstName', 'text', array(
        'constraints' => new MinLength(3),
    ))
    ->add('lastName', 'text', array(
        'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlank(),
            new MinLength(3),
        ),
    ))
;
```

[sources](http://symfony.com/blog/form-goodness-in-symfony-2-1)

Is there a way to assign them to a validation constraint ?

In my case, I have [validation groups depending on submitted data](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-submitted-data)

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Answer (score 3):

OK, well the solution was pretty straighforward actually.

Looking at the [Constraint](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraint.html) class, I noticed the exposed $groups property and    addImplicitGroupName(string $group) method.

When you know that, you know all about it:

```
$cv1 = new NotBlank();
$cv1->groups = array('myGroup');
$cv2 = new NotNull();
$cv2->groups = array('myGroup');
$myCnstrs = array(
    'constraints' => array(
         $cv1,
         $cv2,
     )
);

$myOtherOptions = array(
     ...
);

$builder->add('myField', null, array_merge($myCnstrs,$myOtherOptions));
```

Sorry if I abused by posting a question and replying to it right after...